# connecting to gui of ap

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, switch

I have an Netgear AP setup with a specific IP, and internet connection is from main router to an ethernet line with 3 switches for 3 different places. When I connect the AP to 1st switch i can connect to AP'S IP. But when i connect to 3rd switch, I cannot connect to the AP's IP (to manage the AP) anymore but i can connect to the SSID's Wi-Fi that AP has setup with. I need the AP to be setup with 3rd switch. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: are all the devices on the same IP subnet? is the switch managed or unmanaged? assuming all the switches in the fabric are equally connected, you would not expect an IP service to change its behavior or reach-ability based on where it is in the fabric. VLANs or other advanced features might have an impact, so you may want to check them if it is a managed switch.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  If i still can connect to the AP'S wifi then doesn't it mean the AP has a certain IP got assigned to it which i can use to log in to the gui?

Comment: if they are on the same IP subnet yes but otherwise maybe not. we don't have much knowledge of your network, so we cannot say with surety. Please answer the questions I asked. if it's Yes&No respectively, then I'd start by power-cycling the switches to make sure that they forget that the AP's MAC address was available on switch1, and now notice its available on switch3. when you test connecting to the AP management interface, which switch are you doing it from?

Comment: same ip subnet yes, switch unmanaged, same vlan, equally connected.

Comment: and you are sure you set a static IP address on the AP? is the client you are connecting from on a wired connection (often you can't access management console while on wifi), and have you tried wiring it into switch3 directly? has the client been rebooted? if not can you run `arp -d *` to clear your ARP cache?